# Copy the top value into duplicate id in the same column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In my table some fields are filled by values some fields are empty in the same column.

I have to filled value if the same duplicate id already have value mean i need to copy the value.

[image]

I have to copy district code if that district code already have value for all the states.

Table Structure:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>|| State_code</td>
    <td>|| District</td>
    <td>|| District_code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>XX</td>
    <td>|| 01</td>
    <td>|| DD</td>
    <td>|| 09</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>XX</td>
    <td>|| 01</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 09</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>XX</td>
    <td>|| 01</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 09</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>XX</td>
    <td>|| 01</td>
    <td>|| AA</td>
    <td>|| 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>XX</td>
    <td>|| 01</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>XX</td>
    <td>|| 01</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>YY</td>
    <td>|| 02</td>
    <td>|| CC</td>
    <td>|| 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>YY</td>
    <td>|| 02</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>YY</td>
    <td>|| 02</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>YY</td>
    <td>|| 02</td>
    <td>|| EE</td>
    <td>|| 12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>YY</td>
    <td>|| 02</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>YY</td>
    <td>|| 02</td>
    <td>|| </td>
    <td>|| 12</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

So i have to fill all the district names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the data as text, include column names, rather than a screen shot of part of the data.

Comment: which column is `district code`? I probably need to see at least what that table looks like to understand the problem.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche have u got it ?

Comment: @krock pls run snippet you will get my problem